# Getting 500 error (missing ;) from blobstore upload

Tags: forms, google-app-engine, http, blobstore, google-http-client

I would like to skip the part where an upload URL is sent to the client, and upload directly to the blobstore from the backend. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047095/using-googlehttpclient-to-send-multipart-form-data) to send the multipart request, although I get:

```
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing/_ah/upload/ahB0NTIzNjU4OTY1ODk1Njg5ciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgICAiAs    M. Reason:
<pre>    Missing ';'</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3>    <pre>javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing ';'
at javax.mail.internet.ParameterList.&lt;init&gt;(ParameterList.java:135)
at javax.mail.internet.ContentType.&lt;init&gt;(ContentType.java:72)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.&lt;init&gt;(MimeMultipart.java:98)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.MultipartMimeUtils.parseMultipartRequest(MultipartMimeUtils.java:41)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:173)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:117)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:114)
```

this is the data sent:

```
--__END_OF_PART__
Content-Type: image/bmp
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-disposition: form-data; name="file"

[binary string here]
--__END_OF_PART__--
```

these are the headers:

```
accept-encoding: gzip,
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=__END_OF_PART__
```

and this is the code:

```
BlobstoreService service = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String url = service.createUploadUrl("/upload");

HttpRequestFactory factory = UrlFetchTransport.getDefaultInstance().createRequestFactory();


MultipartFormContent content = new MultipartFormContent();
content.addPart(new MultipartFormContent.Part(
            "file",
            new InputStreamContent("image/bmp", 
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(data)))));

content.writeTo(System.out);

HttpRequest request = factory.buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(new URL(url)), content);
request.getHeaders().setContentType(content.getMediaType().build());
request.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob), the multipart body has to be `multipart/form-data` with input type "file", which produces the `Content-Disposition` header with "filename" section:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="imagename.bmp"
```

With HttpClient it should be something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304663/apache-httpclient-making-multipart-form-post).

Comment: I'm using Google's HttpClient, and not the apache one, because it's provided with app engine already.

Comment: And I've set the filename parameter as well, still the same result